# Adding peaches during the boil or during secondary?

Tags: fruit

I'm thinking about doing a Peach IPA, recipe isn't set in stone yet. I definitely want to taste the peaches, but I don't want it to taste like someone spilled beer in an a peach juice bottle. I'm doing a one gallon batch. I'm trying to decide whether to add the peaches in the initial boil or in a secondary. Are there relative merits to each? Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add peach juice or puree on the chill at 170° to pasteurize or late fermentation when most of your alcohol is present but still enough yeast action to burn up the new sugars.

Answer (score 4):

Most fruits taste the way they do because of the aroma. If you boil the peaches they will taste much less of peach because the aromatics are partially boiled off.

You can try it yourself - boil some peaches for 10 minutes, let them cool, then taste alongside unboiled peaches.  You can then decide if you want them boiled or put in primary once fermentation has slowed.

Answer (score 1):

Secondary, no question.  With the delicate aroma you want to ad as late as possible.  Chop, vacuum seal, freeze.  Thaw them out a couple days before you want to use them.

Comment: I've done frozen cube but found I get much more flavor from juice or puree with much less fruit.. I think it's a basic surface area thing.